# Game played by day or week

Tags: learning

Currently I aking me about How many games by day or week, need a beginner to improve their game.

I asking that because I read a beginner player need to play 80% and study 20%, but How much is this 80%?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no magic number, especially since your definition of "improve" could be different from anyone else's.

I play about 5-10 rapid games per day, and have a few ongoing correspondence games at any time. Then again, I'm not a beginner, and if you're truly a beginner I'd say keep playing games as long as you're enjoying it. No need to keep grinding out more games if you're not having fun. For one, you'll not learn as much, and what's the point of playing a game if you're not enjoying it? Also there's no reason to stop if you've hit the day's "magic number" of games.

Most important is analyzing your games after the fact. If you're reading a chess book (i.e. How to Reassess Your Chess, etc), after you're done with a game go back through the moves and see if you're following the guidelines the author laid down. See what you could've done better. See what you did well.

Saying you'll play 100 games a day to get better won't likely make you better if you're not enjoying it, and aren't following a study plan.

Comment: Thanks for reply, Honestly I enjoy a lot play, but currently I'm playing about 4-6 games by day, each game played Is reviewed. I felt that's not enough but is spend all the time free I have, And now I understand that is not important How many games, only you are enjoying.